# Protect user's information in the referral URL

Tags: php

I decided to refresh my site today with a pair of upgrades. One of them is referring availability. So, as I method of referrer recognition, I am going to use special URL with referrer ID in it (if there is some other but better method, feel free to let me know about it). After I implemented the basics of that availability, I made a decision to make the system more secure. With that, I mean hiding the referrer's ID. Now, I am here, looking for suggestion on how can I make it secure (hidden or encrypted), but still be able to decrypt it on the server-side. Don't suggest me to use Base64 encryption, it's too simple and everyone can decrypt it these days.

I could try making my own system of encryption, what do you think?

Comment: Creating your own system of encryption is a big mistake, always used the tried and tested. You could use a hash of the ID, username and salt key?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to pass.
First of all don't pass info that is not supposed to be publicly passed.
Second, you could create a token, save that in the DB next to the user, and authenticate on that token.
That token could be something that is valid only for a few hours... you make the choice, what works best for you.